# p4 edit giving error : file(s) not on client

Tags: perforce, edit

On doing `p4 edit file1` I am getting `err: file(s) not on client`.
Tried to edit the file1 from the folder where the file is located and also by giving full file path still got same error.

`p4 where` gives 3 paths like :
`//depot/a/b/c/... //workspace-1/a/b/c/... /local/d/e/f/a/b/c/...`

My workspace/client is `workspace-1`, file is present at path `:"/local/d/e/f/a/b/c/"`

workspace/client name is correct in `.p4config` (which is at path : `/local/d/e/f/`)

On doing p4 client, the P4 client spec file shows correct client name and View is :
`//depot/a/b/... //workspace-1/a/b/...`

The issue is that p4 is not referring to client but not sure why
`.p4config` is fine, `env P4CLIENT` is also set.

Why the client is not getting referred?

Comment: Run `p4 set` and `p4 set P4CLIENT`, and post the output.

Comment: It gives correct values: 

[~/a/b/c]$ p4 set

P4CLIENT=workspace-1
>P4PORT=a.f.v:1XXX
>P4USER=a
>P4_a.f.v:1XXX_CHARSET=none (enviro)
>[~/a/b/c]$ p4 set P4CLIENT
>P4CLIENT=workspace-1

Comment: I have observed that P4V is case insensitive for file paths. P4 (the command line version) is case sensitive. Thus when I was copying the file name from command line to P4V to check if the filed existed, P4V was correctly showing the file. With very minute observation I realized that one character in file path had a capital case, while the correct path as in small case. This is how I stumbled upon your question. My answer may help others.

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like your client spec is set up correctly, since `p4 where` is showing the expected thing.  The `file(s) not on client` error means that the file isn't synced.

Do:

```
p4 sync file1
p4 edit file1
```

Comment: On doing p4 sync file1 ... it gives err- No such file .....tried with abs path and also from inside the parent folder

Comment: Maybe the file's not in the depot yet?  If that's the case do `p4 add file1`.